# How to install Cloud zoom in Woocommerce

Tags: installation, cloud, zooming, woocommerce

Today I've bought plugin CLoudzoom for Woocommerce, but I enable plugin already but I see single product it not working. 
Who used this plugin please help me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Under WooCommerce->Settings->General  see "Enable WooCommerce lightbox on the product page."  - make sure the box is checked.

CloudZoom will not work if this box is not checked.

Comment: :( I've enable it. but it not working...please help me. I need it.

Answer (score 2):

We are the developers of Cloud Zoom (V2.0+) and have created a new module to integrate the plugin into WooCommerce/WordPress. In WooCommerce, additional images linked to products will become functional CloudZoom gallery images.

Update: V1.1 Now works with product variation images.

http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/woocommerce

Comment: Hi, great work on that module!!! I've found this question and I wonder if you know how to make it work with the WooThumbs plugin to add image galeries to product variations?

Answer (score 1):

Does Cloud Zoom work with WordPress Swatches? If I swap out the image and hover over the swapped out image, it only shows the "Feature Image". Very frustrating! [image]

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce Cloud Zoom Image Plugin doesn't seem to work with variation images. It is always the featured image that gets zoomed in on.